# restore application data programmatically

Tags: android, backup, restore

how can i restore application data programmatically from SDCard on rooted device???

i am worked on backup/restore applications and i did the following steps:

-Back Up case i copied data app from /data/data/PackageName/ to SDcard

then i removed the application and reinstall it

-Restore case i copied the same data app in backUp from SDcard to /data/data/PackageName/

but the application stopped when i start it?

***sorry about my english***

Comment: Are you talking about the same app here?  Or are you trying to backup the data from one app using another app?

Comment: OK,  Could you post the logcat from the crash?  That would help point us inthe proper direction.

Comment: @Barak i can't post the logcat because my app runnig good and it copy and past the application data of another app correctly but the problem is when i start that application that i copied and pasted data of it from my app it will not start

Answer (score 2):

If application stores data in SDCard then you must backup that data also.... the path of that data is "/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/Packagename/".

Comment: the application that i want to backed up doesn't have any data in "/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/Packagename/" and thank u for your response